# Pattern for avoiding constant values being baked into transpiled output?

Tags: typescript

I'm a noob building a whole app in pure TypeScript. Using Deno, fwiw.

In C# we would avoid using `public const` in a library or module unless the value truly is constant, e.g. `TenMinutes` can't ever be eleven.

This is because the compiler will bake the underlying value into consuming code.

TypeScript uses `const` often and even suggests using `const` for exported values, when it sees the value is never rewritten.

Feels ...wrong.

What's the preferred pattern around this in TypeScript to avoid consumers having not-really-constants baked into its code (esp. when designing packages)?

Comment: Use const most of the time since most variables aren't reassigned. Use CASE_LIKE_THIS for very constant things. You get used to it :) Use let occasionally for variables that get reassigned. Happens rarely IME. It doesn't bake in stuff into the compiled code. The JS it puts out isn't changed at all. There's no way to tell the compiler to inline constant values as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks Trevor, I'm quite enjoying the change :) I added some clarity around the question. I think it's at the package boundaries that the issue I'm worried about might be a problem (or imaginary/my misunderstanding).

Comment: Just learned that `const enum` will get stuff inlined. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#const-enums. If you don't use that, it won't get inlined, even if declared `const`.

Comment: I guess now I'm looking for documentation to confirm that an `export const x = "y"` won't inline `y`.